# Entendiendo el ManyToMany de Eloquent/Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relaciones

tengo la siguiente duda con estas tablas, comencemos: 
Tengo la tabla **monedas** y la tabla **items**.

```
Monedas
----------
- id 
- nombre
- valor


Items
----------
- id 
- nombre
- descripcion
- peso
- daño
- resistencia
```

Entonces aqui me planteé yo : *si diferentes monedas puedes estar en diferentes items a la vez* (n-m) pues creo otra tabla en la relacione **que cantidad de cada moneda vale un item** por tanto al ser de *muchos a muchos* me hecreado un **tercera tabla** llamada **item_precios**.

```
Item_precios
----------
- id 
- cantidad
- item_id
- moneda_id
```

De esa forma ya lo tengo todo controlado. Ahora bien, **¿Que punto de vista cojo para hacer las relaciones con Eloquent en Laravel?** , es decir, la relacion entre moneda e item es **nm-m** pero la relacion entre monedas e item_precio es **1-n**, ¿*a donde quiero llegar*? pues que segun con que lo compare tendre que hacer uno u otro.

Yo la opcion que he decidido es que, como tengo esa **tercera tabla(*item_precios*)** pues voy a hacer como si fuera **1-n** pero claro si siempre se aplica la normalizacion de **n-m** creando una *tabla auxiliar* nunca se deberia de usar el `ManyToMany()` de laravel no?

Y para terminar pues expongo mas detalladamente lo que yo he hecho:

**Mi relacion transformada : 1 Moneda - N Item_precio**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Moneda extends Model
{
    //
    public function item_precio()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemPrecio::class);
    }
}
```

Como se puede apreciar, desde mi punto de vista el `ManyToMany` no se utilizaria nunca ya que al transformarlo pasa a 1-N. Pero si esta es por algo.